# BackgroundWorker completed event - which thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, background

Does the completed event of the BackgroundWorker control come back on the GUI thread or do i have to marshal that back.

Also, does the progress event come back on the GUI thread or do i have to marshal that back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both events will be marshalled onto the UI thread.

Answer (score 3):

All events are going to come back on the thread that created the instance of the BackgroundWorker. All your client has to do is listen for the event.

You've probably been here, but see also: [BackgroundWorker Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker_events.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

It will be raised on the UI thread which originated the operation.  Under the hood, BackgroundWorker uses a [SynchronizationContext](http://themechanicalbride.blogspot.com/2008/11/auto-sizing-canvas-for-silverlight-and.html) to marshaling between the two threads.  Both WPF and WinForms will install an appropriate SynchronizationContext on startup.

Answer (score 2):

If the BackgroundWorker was created from the UI thread, then the both events will also be raised on the UI thread.

If it was created from a background thread, the event will be raised on an undefined background thread.

See this post and this connect issue for more information.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2806824/279999

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/116930/backgroundworker-components-progresschanged-and-runworkercompleted-event-run-on-wrong-thread