# BackgroundWorker RunWorkerCompleted Event

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events, backgroundworker

My C# application has several background workers.  Sometimes one background worker will fire off another.  When the first background worker completes and the `RunWorkerCompleted` event is fired, on which thread will that event fire, the UI or the first background worker from which `RunWorkerAsync` was called?  I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition.  Any thoughts or suggestions you may have would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If the `BackgroundWorker` was created from the UI thread, then the `RunWorkerCompleted` event will also be raised on the UI thread.

If it was created from a background thread, the event will be raised on an undefined background thread (not necessarily the same thread, unless you're using a custom `SynchronizationContext`).

Interestingly, this doesn't seem to be all that well-documented on MSDN.  The best reference I was able to find was [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx):

> The preferred way to implement multithreading in your application is to use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) component. The [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) component uses an event-driven model for multithreading. **The background thread runs your [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) event handler, and the thread that creates your controls runs your [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) and [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event handlers.** You can call your controls from your [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) and [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event handlers.

Comment: Would this be where the control was instantiated?  All of my background workers are instantiated (presumably) from the UI thread in the default `InitializeComponent()` function.

Comment: @Jim: Yes, slightly poor wording on the original take; it's actually the thread that created the `BackgroundWorker` that will receive the events, and you must call `RunWorkerAsync` from the same thread.  For sanity purposes, that should generally be the UI thread.

Comment: This isn't correct.  It will only get raised on the UI thread if the UI thread created the BGW instance.  If a thread created the BGW then it will be raised on an arbitrary threadpool thread.

Comment: @Hans: What is the difference between what you said and what I said?

Comment: "will be raised on the same thread", not the case if it wasn't created on the UI thread.  Marshaling a call to an arbitrary thread is not possible, only the UI thread has the required plumbing.  A WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext or DispatcherSynchronizationContext provider is required, the default provider (SynchronizationContext) makes callbacks on a threadpool thread.

Comment: @Hans: Alright, I've made this more clear.  As long as we're nitpicking, it doesn't *have* to be the UI thread; you can create your own `SynchronizationContext` that *does* synchronize.

Comment: Also, we got confused because you also have to call RunWorkerAsync from the main thread.  That's most important.  We had a timer to collect BGWs and kick them off.  The difference between System.Timers.Timer and System.Windows.Forms.Timer was the difference between OnWorkerCompleted being invoked from main thread and a random thread.  System.Timers.Timer events aren't invoked on the main thread.

Comment: Based on my experience from just now, and based on this post (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e61819bd-dcb6-4d68-a490-1b3ad70147af/backgroundworker-calls-runworkercompleted-event-on-worker-thread?forum=wpf) the RunWorkerCompleted() is called on the thread that called `RunWorkerAsync`. So the first version of your answer was more correct. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527442/why-does-the-backgroundworker-not-call-the-runworkercompleted-on-the-right-threa

Comment: @TobiasKnauss: Nope, the current version is correct. The callback runs within the same *Synchronization Context*, not the same *thread*.  If `RunWorkerAsync` is called from a random `ThreadPool` thread, I can practically guarantee you that the callback won't run on the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

From my observation, the RunWorkerCompleted is executed on the thread that called RunWorkerAsync, which is not necessarily the thread that CREATED the background worker.

Answer (score -1):

On same issue found this thread [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e61819bd-dcb6-4d68-a490-1b3ad70147af/backgroundworker-calls-runworkercompleted-event-on-worker-thread?forum=wpf).

> It's all about the SynchronizationContext.
>
> Windows Forms will automatically overwrite any existing
> SynchronizationContext by default when it creates a window; see
> WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall:
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext.autoinstall.aspx
>
> BackgroundWoker captures the SynchronizationContext when
> RunWorkerAsync is called, not when it is constructed (note that this
> is an implementation detail, not documented). It then uses that
> captured SynchronizationContext to execute RunWorkerCompleted.
>
> So, the thread that runs RunWokerCompleted is actually determined by
> SynchronizationContext.Current at the time RunWorkerAsync is called.
>
> WPF provides a DispatcherSynchronizationContext that will marshal the
> call to its UI thread. Windows Forms provides a
> WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext that will marshal the call to its
> UI thread. When doing WPF/Forms interop, both systems share a single
> UI thread. You mentioned this is all in the context of an MFC app; in
> this case, MFC doesn't provide a SynchronizationContext (of course),
> but it would share its thread with the WPF and Forms thread (they all
> share a single UI thread).
>
> One more piece of information: the default SynchronizationContext will
> queue actions (e.g., RunWorkerCompleted) to the ThreadPool. This
> sounds like the behavior you're seeing. This default behavior kicks in
> if SynchronizationContext.Current is null at the time RunWorkerAsync
> is called.
>
> So, it sounds like closing out the Windows Forms form may be clearing
> SynchronizationContext.Current. Windows Forms does have the notion of
> a "main form", so it may be doing that since it thinks the last form
> of the application just closed.
>
> I recommend: 1) Testing if SynchronizationContext.Current is in fact
> null at the time RunWorkerCompleted is called, and possibly also
> testing before and after the Windows Forms form is displayed. Just to
> make sure this is the problem. 2) Setting
> SynchronizationContext.Current (via
> SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext) after the Windows
> Forms form closes. Pass "new DispatcherSynchronizationContext()" as
> the argument.
>
> Alternatively, if the Windows Forms form is a modal dialog, you can
> use the ScopedSynchronizationContext class from my Nito.Async library
> (http://www.codeplex.com/NitoAsync), which is a very simple class used
> to temporarily replace SynchronizationContext.Current, resetting it to
> its original value at the end of its "using" block.
>
> More information on the various SynchronizationContext types is on my
> blog:
> http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/10/synchronizationcontext-properties.html

. In short insert

```
AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(this.Dispatcher)
```

before RunWorkerAsync call.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).