# which thread does backgroundworker completed event handler run on?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a GUI application that needs to run long calculations (think a minute or more) and the way that it deals with this is by giving the calculation to a background worker.  (this part is fine)

The question I have is if I do something like:
this.backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.doSomethingElse);

is doSomethingElse going to be run on the main UI thread or whatever in the thread pool the background worker ran on?

thank for any help you can provide.

Comment: You could write the `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` to the output window in the `UI`, `DoWork` and `WorkCompleted` to confirm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's going to be run in the same thread that BackgroundWorker is in, ie most usually the UI thread.

Comment: Ok to the 2nd part, but a Bgw (or any other object) is not 'in a thread'.

Comment: Sorry, the thread that spawned it would have been a better wording

Comment: This brings up an interesting point actually.. if you use the visual GUI designer in a windows forms application to declare a BackgroundWorker, does the actual BackgroundWorker object end up on the stack for the UI thread or on the heap?

Comment: Afaik it's not really the thread that creates the bgw that matters. It will somehow find the MessagePump through the execution context. Or something like that.

Comment: Although this is true, I still sometimes find that I get cross-thread errors by showing a dialog or doing something with UI controls inside the Completed() method. I feel that I still need to check for InvokeRequired and use Invoke() on the control to make sure.

Answer (score 5):

> is doSomethingElse going to be run on the main UI thread

Yes, that is the main reason of being for a Backgroundworker. It has 3 events, only DoWork will be executed on a separate (ThreadPool) thread. Completed and ProgressChanged will be marshaled to the 'main' thread.

Answer (score 4):

If the BackgroundWorker was created from the UI thread, then the RunWorkerCompleted event will also be raised on the UI thread.

If it was created from a background thread, the event will be raised on an undefined background thread.

See this post and this connect issue for more information.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2806824/279999

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/116930/backgroundworker-components-progresschanged-and-runworkercompleted-event-run-on-wrong-thread

Comment: Indeed! The first time I was confused this fact when my application worked fine, and Completed event was invoked from main UI thread. But my unit tests failed as far as Completed event was invoked from background thread, not from main test thread