# How to fix my Background solution to make thread-safe calls?

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I tried to set Text property of TextBox from another thread. I got this exception below;

```
"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'recTpcTxt' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."
```

Then, I used BackgroundWorker to solve this issue. However, I faced with the same exception message.

**EDIT[1]:**
*Actually, I take a guide myself this link ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx. I can solve my problem by using invokeproperty. However, I cannot solve my problem with backgroundworker.*

Is there something wrong in my solution? How do I fix my solution to set some property of UI variable?

**EDIT[2]:** *More code to clarify the issue;*

MqttManager.cs;

```
public partial class MqttManager : Form
    {
        MqttHandler mqttHandler = new MqttHandler();
        public static MqttManager managerInst;

        public MqttManager()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            managerInst = this;
            ...
        }

        ...

        private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;

        public void NotifyUIForRecMsg(string topic, string message)
        {
            object[] objArr = { topic, message };
            this.backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(objArr);
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            e.Result = e.Argument;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(
            object sender,
            RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            object[] res = (object[])e.Result;
            this.recTpcTxt.Text = (String)res[0];
        }
    }
```

MqttManager.Design.cs;

```
partial class MqttManager
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            ...

            this.backgroundWorker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
            this.backgroundWorker.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker_DoWork);
            this.backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }
        #endregion

        ...
     }
```

MqttHandler.cs;

```
class MqttHandler
    {
        MqttClient client;

        ...

        /// <summary>
        /// Publish received event handler.
        /// </summary>
        private void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(Object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
        {
            MqttManager.managerInst.NotifyUIForRecMsg(e.Topic, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message));
        }
     }
```

Comment: You are misusing `BackgroundWorker`. It is intended to do background work not updating UI. Why not update UI just from `NotifyUIForRecMsg`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, I cannot update UI bu just using NotifyUIForRecMsg. I got the exception that I told above.

Comment: Why `NotifyUIForRecMsg` is in non-UI thread? You should provide more code and clarify the issue.

Comment: If you have some long-running operation which raises `HandlePublishReceivedEvent` (by the way, the name `HandlePublishReceivedEvent` is not suitable for event handler) you should run that operation in backgound worker.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan , I fixed the name of event handler method and added more code to clarify the issue!

Comment: The BackgroundWorker can be started from any thread. If it is started from the UI thread (for example in a click handler for a button), the "completed" event will be executed in the UI thread and can access GUI elements like text boxes. **But if the BackgroundWorker is started from a different thread, the event will be executed in a[nother] different thread.** Apparently. Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220239/which-thread-does-backgroundworker-completed-event-handler-run-on. The safe thing is to just always check "InvokeRequired". That costs time, but in a GUI time is usually plenty.

Comment: You should call `RunWorkerAsync` from UI thread to get `RunWorkerCompleted` raised in same thread. Still unclear how the `client_MqttMsgPublishReceived` invoked? I think you need another instance of `BackgrouneWorker`.

Comment: Clarified me well. Thanks for your recommendations :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx

Basically, to set a control propertiy you have to be in the same UI thread.

This simple solution move the call to `textbox1.Text = someText` in the UI thread

```
private void SetText(string text)
{
    // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
    // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
    // If these threads are different, it returns true.
    if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {   
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
    }
    else
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

also, you can use `textBox1.BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`: it will run in UI thread, without locking the caller thread waiting for `SetText` delegate to be completed

[Edit] to do it in your backgroundWorker:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    object[] arg = (object[])e.Argument;
    SetTextToTextBox(recTpcTxt, (string)arg[0]);
    SetTextToTextBox(recMsgTxt, (string)arg[1]);
}

private void SetTextToTextBox(TextBox toSet, string text)
{
    // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
    // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
    // If these threads are different, it returns true.
    if (toSet.InvokeRequired)
    {   
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        toSet.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
    }
    else
    {
        toSet.Text = text;
    }
}
```

[Edit 2]
To properly use backgroundworker

Register for events `DoWork` and `RunWorkerCompleted`

```
this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
```

Before exiting `backgroundWorker1_DoWork`, set result property of eventArgs, and read them in `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted`

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    e.Result = new string[] { "one", "two" };
}
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(
    object sender,
    RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] res = (string[])e.Result;
    this.textBox1.Text = res[0];
}
```

Comment: I've just edited my problem above. I already used your recommendation. It solved my problem. But I want to apply backgroundworker solution in problem.

Comment: why cannot I solve my problem by just using backgroundworker? In the link I mention in the question, backgroundworker can be used to make thread-safe calls. Backgroundworker is mentioned in this link as a alternative way of solution, besides using "invoke".

Comment: Your last edited solution is nice to show parameter-passing from doWork method to runWorkerCompleted method. However, I still get the exception; {"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'recTpcTxt' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."} when I pass parameter from doWork to runWorkerCompleted and try to set text property of textbox in runWorkerCompleted method.

Comment: It worked in my test, I think maybe you are starting background thread in a thread that's not the UI one. see @peter-schneider comment to your question.
The expected use of BackgroundWorker is: start a long operation form UI thread, register for its events that will be run in the UI thread, where you can handle controls properties, if you have strated the worker in the correct thread. As far as I understand, you want to start the bgworker from a different thread, that's not what it is meant to do

Comment: I understand well Gian. Thanks for your contribution :)

Comment: you're welcome @séan35. Please mark my answer as accepted if you think it was useful for you.