# C# Process.Start, Thread.IsBackGround, BackgroundWorker and .Net.Remoting

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker, .net-remoting, process.start

I need an advice because I'm "locked"...

I have a client-server application using .NetRemoting between the client process and the server one.

Server process raises events to the client calling a method.

Then, the client uses a BackGroundWorker to transmit values to User Interface. 


Usualy, the server is already running when the client is launched.

- When BackGroundWorker.DoWork() is called, Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground equals True

- In BackGroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted event, Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground equals **False**


But, if, during the client is loading (.exe is opening), it needs to open (with Process.Start()) the Server process (.exe) before it connects

then, in BackGroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted, Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground is still equal to **True** and UI can not be changed in this thread.

In that case, I need to open an other client (connecting to the same server) to have a good behavior.



What could be the difference between these two situations ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you creating the BackgroundWorker on a non-UI thread?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806814/c-backgroundworker-runworkercompleted-event/2806824#2806824

Answer (score 0):

What you should have:

Client:
--UI thread: starts BGWorker and runs BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
--Backgroundthread: runs BackgroundWorker.DoWork, communicates with server

<->

Server: communicates with client

Why isn't your server already running when your client is starting? + Why use remoting if they're running on the same machine??

Comment: my server is an application server. Clients are WinForm, Web browsers or simple class. You can visit http://edv.edvariables.net for few images but presentation is in french, as well my UI is. Sorry (too much job to translate it).

Answer (score 0):

I've found the (a) solution :
In the client startup :

```
lChannelTCP = new TcpChannel(lProps, provider, providerSrv);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(lChannelTCP, false);
```

or (haven't test wich one)

```
RemotingConfiguration.ApplicationName = "EDV";
```

has to be set **before** Server process is started !