# BackgroundWorker and ConcurrentQueue

Tags: c#, queue, backgroundworker, filesystemwatcher, concurrent-queue

I have a `FileSystemWatcher` which is looking for new files, putting the filenames in a `Queue`.
In a seperate Thread the Queue is worked off. My code is working, but I question if there could be information lost, because of the asynchronous process. Please watch the code explained by comments:
(I think maybe I need something like a thread lock somewhere?)
(Code is simplified)

```
public class FileOperatorAsync
{
  private ConcurrentQueue<string> fileQueue;
  private BackgroundWorker worker;
  private string inputPath;

  public FileOperatorAsync(string inputPath)
  {
     this.inputPath = inputPath;
     fileQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
     worker = new BackgroundWorker();
     worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
     worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
     Start();
  }

  void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
     try
     {
        string file;
        while (!worker.CancellationPending && fileQueue.TryDequeue(out file)) //As long as queue has files
        {
          //Do hard work with file
        }
        //Thread lock here?
        //If now Filenames get queued (Method Execute -> Worker is still busy), they wont get recognized.. or?
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        //Logging
     }
     finally
     {
        e.Cancel = true;
     }
  }

  public void Execute(string file) //called by the FileSystemWatcher
  {
     fileQueue.Enqueue(file);
     Start(); //Start only if worker is not busy
  }

  public void Start()
  {
     if (!worker.IsBusy)
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
  }

  public void Stop()
  {
     worker.CancelAsync();
  }

}
```

Comment: Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you may have a problem with `Execute`. It can leave a `file` unprocessed by your `worker`.

You can solve it in two ways:
1) Your `worker` doesn't finish after processing all queued files. It waits on a `AutoResetEvent` for next file to process. In that case `Execute` should notify the `worker` by calling `AutoResetEvent.Set`.
Example:

```
AutoResetEvent event;
...
// in worker_DoWork
while(!worker.CancellationPending){
    event.WaitOne();
    // Dequeue and process all queued files
}

...
// in Execute
fileQueue.Enqueue(file);
event.Set();
```

2) Your worker finishes after processing all queued files (as you do now) but you can check in `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` whether there are still files to process and run the worker once again.
In that case if `Execute` hasn't started the `worker` because it was busy then the `worker` will be started again in `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` and the pending `file` will be processed.

```
// in  worker_RunWorkerCompleted
if (!fileQueue.IsEmpty())
    Start();
```

**Note**: if you decide to use `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` in a non-GUI application then you should be careful in `Start` because `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` can be invoked not on the thread where you call `Execute` and a race condition will occur in `Start`. More info: [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted and threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822784/backgroundworker-runworkercompleted-and-threading)

if you call `Start()` from two different threads simultaneously then they both can see that `worker.IsBusy == false` and they both will call `worker.RunWorkerAsync()`. The thread which calls `worker.RunWorkerAsync()` a little later than another thread will throw an `InvalidOperationException`. So you should catch that exception or wrap `IsBusy`+`RunWorkerAsync` into a critical section with a lock to avoid the race condition and the exception throwing.

Comment: Thanks! I used your second solution. Yes it is a non-GUI application. Thanks for the Note! "Execute" is called by the FileSystemWatcher Created Event, so its already executed by different Threads, but its still synchronous?

Comment: @J.D. I've added one more note to my answer to address your question. I hope I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

To not to have to worry about the problem, when the queue is empty and `Start` is called before the worker exits, you can try not leaving the worker method at all:

```
while (!worker.CancellationPending)
{
    while (!worker.CancellationPending && !fileQueue.TryDequeue(out file))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }

    if (worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        break;
    }
    //
}
```

Other possibility, without the inelegant sleeping would be to use the `ManualResetEvent` class to signal when the queue is empty and stops being empty.

Comment: The Problem is not the Queue itself. The Queue is working fine and stable. I am worrying about items which are enqueued after the dequeuing is finished.  Please look at the spot where I put the "//Thread lock here?" Comment

Comment: @J.D. It's unclear what do you want to achieve. There is no code there, so obviously no lock is needed. As for adding items - `Enqueue` method is also synchronized.

Comment: Yes, there is not that much code afterwards, but I think there could be still milliseconds passing...  I just want to make it as safe as possible.

Comment: @J.D. But why would you want to `lock`? What operations exactly are you trying to synchronize?

Comment: On "//Thread lock here?" I want the Execute() Method to wait, till worker_DoWork is finished, so worker.IsBusy = false

Comment: @J.D. Ok, now I understand your concern. See my edit.

Comment: I implemented your sleep solution first, but without the sleep, which lead to 100% CPU usage :D So I tried to improve it without an infinity loop. I will take a look at the ManualResetEvent. Thanks!