# Clever event accessors - to fire handlers on the thread they were registered?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, delegates, dispatcher

Have just had an idea, I haven't seen it before, wondering if you guys thought it was a good idea, if it exists, any common pitfalls etc. - and also how to implement it.

There are several times I've found myself subscribing to an event from the UI thread that will be called from a different thread - for example, notification of a service call completing.

'My' idea would be to store the current `Dispatcher` in the `add` block along with the handler delegate, then when the event is 'fired', perform some extra logic/checks to see if there was a dispatcher associated with the handler, and `Invoke` on it if necessary.

Of course it would only work on threads with a `Dispatcher` (or Forms equivalent - something with a message pump I guess).  I guess the usefulness and cleanliness depends on whether the event subscriber should have to worry about the thread the handler is called or not?

---

Edit: Sounds like it's not such a bad thing then - additionally does anyone have any idea how to implement?  Using `Delegate.Combine` how could you call each handler on a different `Dispatcher`, for example?  Would you instead store delegates in a composite object in a `List`, and invoke them in turn in the `On(Whatever)` method, or is there something nicer?

...Looking at the `BackgroundWorker` source in Reflector, there's nothing to Invoke:

```
protected virtual void OnProgressChanged(ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ProgressChangedEventHandler handler = (ProgressChangedEventHandler) base.Events[progressChangedKey];
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

Unless I'm missing something?

---

So then `BackgroundWorker` does it with an `AsyncOperation`.  How about a general solution, just for event handlers, in the event accessors?  `BackgroundWorker` can get away with the way it works because a method is called from the client - in the more general case, the only time you'll have access to the handler's thread is in the event accessor? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, that's exactly what the `BackgroundWorker` is doing in its `RunWorkerCompleted` and `ProgressChanged` events. So it can't be *that* bad.
I can't find a real proof, that the `BackgroundWorker` is doing it, I just read it somewhere. When you [google for it](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=BackgroundWorker%20RunWorkerCompleted%20marshaled%20to%20ui%20thread), you will find more hints. If someone can provide a link, I would be happy.

**UPDATE:**
Because it isn't so easy to find this behavior in the BackgroundWorker, I provide my analysis:
The `BackgroundWorker` is using an `AsyncOperation` for raising the events. Inside this class, the events are posted to a `SynchronizationContext`. Only then are the methods `OnProgressChanged` and `OnRunWorkerCompleted` executed. This means, those methods are already executed on the right thread.

In some more detail, the following happens, when `RunWorkerAsync` is called:

1. An `AsyncOperation` instance is created via `AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation`. This saves the current `SynchronizationContext`. As we are still in the UI thread, this is the context of the UI thread.
2. The background operation is started and calls into the private method `WorkerThreadStart`. This method is running in the background thread and executes `OnDoWork` which in turn raises the `DoWork` event. This means, the `DoWork` event is **not** raised in the UI thread.
3. After `OnDoWork` completed, the `PostOperationCompleted` method of the `AsyncOperation` instance is executed which in turn calls `AsyncOperation.Post` which calls  `SynchronizationContext.Post` which in turn will call indirectly `OnRunWorkerCompleted` on the UI thread.
4. When `ReportProgress` is called, a similar thing happens: `AsyncOperation.Post` is called directly and will invoke the `OnProgressChanged` method on the UI thread.

[`AsyncOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperation.aspx) and [`AsyncOperationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperationmanager.createoperation.aspx) are public and can be used to implement a similar behavior in your classes.

Comment: Very true - that's one of the things that makes it so easy to work with the background worker - you already are on the right thread in the callback handlers. Also see this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670526/backgroundworker-completed-event-which-thread

Comment: I took a quick look at the `BackgroundWorker` source and couldn't find anything - question updated - am I missing something?

Comment: @BrokenGlass: About your link: google search turns up stuff like this, but nothing "official"...

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone: Hey, now that is interesting!

Comment: @Kieren & @BrokenGlass: Please see update to my answer for an analysis of this feature in the `BackgroundWorker` class.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar with Castle DynamicProxy, where it intercepts calls and does an `IsInvokeRequired/Invoke` on them.