# How to get the Thread to Invoke in DotNet

Tags: .net, multithreading, invoke, dispatcher

If I have minimum 2 classes. One class creates the Bitmap and the other draws the bitmap on UI form. I want to ask you if there is any variable I can transport from UIClass to the GeneratorClass except the whole Form or any control. I prefer to transport the "Thread" as property from UIClass to GeneratorClass and in GeneratorClass I can create the image there by invoking in UIThread.

I know:

```
Control.Invoke(Delegate, Parameters)
```

Or in WPF

```
Control.Dispatcher(Delegate, Parameters)
```

I also know

```
System.Threading.Thread(ThreadStart)
```

I prefer to only have a "Thread-Variable" to work with to start Invoking or to use Dispatcher to stay on WPF and WinForms and GeneratorClass with same Thread.

Thanks for your ideas (preferred in VB.Net)

*** My working answer ***

use the shared `Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current` to receive the current UI Thread. Then use 
 `GuiThread.Send(AddressOf MyMethode, MyParameters)` to work in UI thread.

```
 Private Sub CreateTestImage()
        'This methode is needed to work in Ui Thread
        Dim SyncContext As Threading.SynchronizationContext = Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current 'Read current UI Thread and store it to variable
        If Me._UseMultiThreading = True Then
            'call methode WITH multthreading
            Dim ThS As New Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf CreateTestImageAsync)
            Dim Th As New Threading.Thread(ThS)
            Th.SetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.STA)
            Th.Start(SyncContext)
        Else
            'call methode WITHOUT multthreading
            Call CreateTestImageAsync(SyncContext)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Methode in thread:

```
Private Sub CreateTestImageAsync(ByVal obj As Object)
    'Callback is only supporting As Object. 
    'Cast it back the the SynchronizationContext 
    Dim GuiThread As Threading.SynchronizationContext = CType(obj, Threading.SynchronizationContext)

    'Do some stuff

    GuiThread.Send(AddressOf ImageCreated, ImgInfo) 'Call methode in UI thread
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would pass the current `SynchronizationContext` to the thread.
in your thread it would look something like this:

```
void ThreadMethod(object parameter)
{
    var context = (SynchronizationContext)parameter;

    context.Send((s) => TheMethodYouWantToRunOnTheUiThread(), null);
}
```

You would start your thread like this:

```
var newThread = new Thread(ThreadMethod);
newThread.Start(SynchronizationContext.Current);
```

It is in C#, but I think you can translate it.

BTW: This is the very same mechanism used by the [`BackgroundWorker` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to marshal the events `ProgressChanged` and `Completed` to the UI thread. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583503/clever-event-accessors-to-fire-handlers-on-the-thread-they-were-registered/5583534#5583534) for more info on this topic